# Not able to start start-hbase.sh

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, hbase

I had Java installed inside Program Files and while installing HBase in Windows, I reinstalled it in C drive. When I try to start start-hbase.sh, it points to the old path. I had changed the Java_Home and Path and restarted my machine. This is the error I get when I double-click the start-hbase.sh:

**/c/Java/hbase-1.1.2/bin/hbase: line 400: /cygdrive/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_6
5/bin/java: No such file or directory
/c/Java/hbase-1.1.2/bin/hbase: line 400: /cygdrive/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_6
5/bin/java: No such file or directory
starting master, logging to C:\Java\hbase-1.1.2/logs/hbase--master-TCT-NB-J0G606
2.out
C:\Java\hbase-1.1.2/bin/hbase: line 400: /cygdrive/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_6
5/bin/java: No such file or directory**

[Java installation directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeZeR.png)
Here is my Path:

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\protobuf;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\cURL\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\

This is the error I get when I try to start hbase using the ./start-hbase.sh command:

**cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to C:\Java\hbase-1.1.2/logs/hbase-TA-MX+User(9402)-master-TCT-NB-J0G6062.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
starting regionserver, logging to C:\Java\hbase-1.1.2/logs/hbase-TA-MX+User(9402)-1-regionserver-TCT-NB-J0G6062.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer**

I see the second part in other stackoverflow links, but those solutions did not work for me (like setting the unix path and using quotes)

Comment: A cygwin path is `:` delimited.

Comment: Didn't understand you. Could you please elaborate or let me know where exactly I have to change something?